# How can I parse object from one function to another?

Tags: javascript, object

How can I parse an object from one function to another function?

I know I am doing it wrong. Any recommended code correction?

```js
viewer.selectedEntityChanged.addEventListener(function(entity) {
  if (Cesium.defined(entity) && Cesium.defined(entity.label)) {
    alert(entity); // produce [object Object
    checkPrice(entity);
  }
  //}
});
```

Comment: what does _**parse**_ mean within the little context that was provided to us.

Comment: If `entity` is a non-circular Object, you can do `alert(JSON.stringify(entity));`. Because `alert` takes a String, and if you pass it anything else, it will just apply `toString` on it, resulting in `[object Object]` in the case of an Object. But using `console.log(entity);` and opening your browser's developer console would be more convinient (no need to close the alert every time you're trying to debug)

Comment: _**important note**_ ... The function  expression that gets provided anonymously as event handler has one argument that is named `entity`. This `entity` then is supposed to have a property called `label`. But the first argument of an event handler is supposed to be a some kind of an `event` object/type. Thus I'm left puzzled what kind of `addEventListener` the OP is dealing with.

Comment: [CesiumJS :: doc :: Viewer.selectedEntityChanged](https://cesium.com/docs/cesiumjs-ref-doc/Viewer.html#selectedEntityChanged)